# Are these highlighted lines part of actual code?

Tags: c, embedded, signal-processing

I was randomly searching for help related to old dsp kit6713 and i came across some links,one of interest is below

http://www.geethanjaliinstitutions.com/engineering/labmanuals/downloads/ece/dsp%20lab.pdf

On page 90/91 of document available on above link,there is a code,i have also attached snapshot of that code and highlighted the two lines with yellow color.

I wonder,in last line of snap,which value of filter_coeff (having red mark above)is being used here inside while loop in main function?from the two highlighted lines or the one below highlighted lines ?

[image]

Comment: They're comments, which are part of the source code.

Comment: The lines beginning with `//` are comments, so they're not executed. Only the value in the uncommented line is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C single line comments begin with `//` so the two highlighted lines are comments which have no impact on the running code. The `filter_coeff` in use is the third one, the one that isn't highlighted. Presumably the three options are provided as common defaults. You could comment out the third `filter_coeff` and uncomment one of the others to change the band range, or you could presumably make your own `filter_coeff` if you knew exactly which values to use.